# How do I find a constant value that seperates elements in an array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have sorted the user input array with my bubble sort. Next I have a function that goes to find a value that separates every element in the array equally. 
My sorting code is such so

Note LENGTH is defined at 25

```
void bubblesort(int dataset[])
{
  int numpasses;
  int lcv;
  int temp;

  for(numpasses = 1; numpasses < LENGTH; numpasses++)
  {
    for(lcv = 0; lcv < LENGTH - numpasses; lcv++)
    {
      if(dataset[lcv] > dataset[lcv + 1])
      {
        temp = dataset[lcv];
        dataset[lcv] = dataset[lcv + 1];
        dataset[lcv + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Next my function to find the constant value is as below

```
int findconstant(int dataset[])
{
  int lcv;
  int constantvalue;

  for(lcv = 0; lcv < LENGTH; lcv++)
  {
    if ((dataset[lcv + 1] - dataset[lcv]) == (dataset[lcv + 2] - dataset[lcv + 1]))
    {
      constantvalue = dataset[lcv + 1] - dataset[lcv];
    }
    else
    {
      constantvalue = 0;
    }
  }
  return(constantvalue);
}
```

and lastly, my output code is below

```
void printdata(int dataset[], int constantvalue)
{
  int lcv;
  if(constantvalue != 0)
  {
    for(lcv = 0; lcv < LENGTH; lcv++)
    {
      printf("Constant value %d separates the elements: %d\n", constantvalue, dataset[lcv]);
    }
  }else
  {
    printf("No constant value that separates the elements.");
  }
}
```

My problem is I always get "No constant value that separates the elements." as my output even if I enter 1 to 25, and the value 1 is the constant value I get the wrong print statement. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong? I am certain on the code for the bubble sort as I sourced it from a book, so perhaps my function to find the constant value is wrong.

Comment: Needs more [mcve].

Comment: This is a straightforward debugging problem. It might take a while but it is solvable simply by turning on your debugger or with some well-placed `printf`s. I suggest you solve this on your own and learn to debug in the process.

Comment: What is the value of LENGTH? Is it constant? How does it work correctly in both findconstant and print data?

Comment: You don't show how/where you call `printdatata`.

Comment: @skyblade1234  In this condition if ((dataset[lcv + 1] - dataset[lcv]) == (dataset[lcv + 2] - dataset[lcv + 1])) there is access memory beyond the array. So this part of the program has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the loop

```
for (lcv = 0; lcv < LENGTH; lcv++)
```

should be with different condition, e.g.

```
for (lcv = 0; lcv < LENGTH-2; lcv++)
```

because statement

```
(dataset[lcv + 2] - dataset[lcv + 1])
```

will go out the array of size `LENGTH` when `lcv == LENGTH-2` and `lcv == LENGTH-1` (two last iterations of loop) and operate with incorrect values (not array values).

I think you should reconsider the approach you use in `findconstant`.

**UPDATE**

Just to illustarete the source of your problem, run the simple program:

```cpp
#define LENGTH 10
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int dataset[LENGTH];
    int lcv;
    for (lcv = 0; lcv < LENGTH; lcv++)
    {
        dataset[lcv] = 1;
    }
    for (lcv = 0; lcv < LENGTH; lcv++)
    {
        printf("%d %d %d\n", dataset[lcv], dataset[lcv + 1], dataset[lcv + 2]);
    }
}
```

and you will see something like (not exactly, but similar)

[image]

in my output I see values `-858993460` and `5241012` that are taken near the array as `dataset[LENGTH]` and `dataset[LENGTH+1]` - parhaps you will take other values, but in any case such values leads to incorrect results of your program. You should read more about [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) to see other possible problems.